# JavaScript: Why isn't this callback function not working?

Tags: javascript, callback

It says: TypeError: myFunc is not a function

I want the output to be  "I am happy, haha!".

I'm learning callback functions in JS.

```
function emotions(myString, myFunc) {
    console.log("I am " + myString + ", " + myFunc(2));
}
var laugh = function(val) {
    var ha="";
    for(var i=0;i<val; i++) {
        ha=ha+"ha";
    }
    return ha;
};

emotions("happy",laugh(2));
```

Comment: See the dupetarget. `emotions` = `setTimeout`, `laugh` = the `setTimeout` callback.

Comment: `emotions('happy', laugh)` willl work. Kind of. Doing `emotions("happy",laugh(2))` is essentially equal to `emotions("happy",'haha')`. For the callback you need to provide a function. So in your example you would do `emotions("happy",function(){return laugh(2);})`

Comment: One of the important features of JavaScript is that it treats functions as data. In the trade, we say that functions are first class citizens. That is how callbacks work: you pass the function as a piece of data to another function. In JavaScript, then you sometimes call, execute, run the function, and you sometimes simply assign it. If you think of a function as a coffee maker, you sometimes want the coffee and you sometimes want the machine itself. _continued …_

Comment: … If you want the _result_ of the function (the coffee), you run it by adding parentheses to the name: `doit()`. If you want the function iteself (the coffee maker) you refer to it _without_ the parentheses. That was your mistake: `laugh(2)` is the _result_ of the function, not the function itself. If you want it to be a callback, it needs to be `laugh` without the parentheses. The only other problem is that you can’t simply pass additional parameters with a callback, so you can’t simply include the `2`.

Comment: @Manngo Wow. Thanks a lot for explaining 'callback' beautifully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
emotions("happy", laugh);
```

You're having that issue because you're no passing the function itself, but it's result as the parameter. When you do `laugh()` you are running the function, not using it's reference, hence, you're passing it's result instead.

The call will the executed inside the `emotions` function as `laugh(2)`, so that's the correct way.

```js
function emotions(myString, myFunc) {
    console.log("I am " + myString + ", " + myFunc(2));
}
var laugh = function(val) {
    var ha="";
    for(var i=0;i<val; i++) {
        ha=ha+"ha";
    }
    return ha;
};

console.log(emotions("happy",laugh));
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me why emotions("happy",laugh(2)); didn't work?

Comment: @Abhayav read the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood now.